# AWS. How can I check if the image running in ECR is an AMI image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I'm new to several of these Amazon functionalities. It looks like I need an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) image to connect it to Amazon Cloudwatch. If it is not an AMI image, I need a way more complicated setup. I'd like to know if the images running in my Amazon ECR are AMI images, plz help.

Comment: An Amazon Machine Image is for creating a virtual machine, which is an EC2 instance. ECR is for storing docker images, used for creating containers. So an AMI would never be in ECR. Please restate your question to detail the actual problem you are trying to solve so that we might help you.

Comment: Hi @MarkB, your comment did help me. So, I asked because I suspected I didn't have an AMI image. I thought it had something to do with Docker. The problem I'm trying to solve is that I don't see the logs in Amazon Cloudwatch, even after declaring the `logConfiguration` in the task definition. I guess it has nothing to do with AMIs.

Comment: If you are using ECS to run docker images, and you have the log configuration correctly configured to send logs to CloudWatch, but you are not seeing any logs there, then the most likely issue is that you aren't giving the Task Execution Role the correct permissions to write logs to CloudWatch.

Comment: It has the permissions. However, the logs are not arriving at CloudWatch. I need to know what might be happening and don't know how. The container stops with exit code 0. How can I run a `docker inspect` in Fargate?

Comment: You can't run `docker inspect` in Fargate. You could try using `ecs exec` to get into the instance and see what is happening. Of course the container has to be running for that to work. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html

Comment: I see. Thanks! I'm going to ask a different question now. I need to know how to debug this stopped container.

Comment: I saw your other question. There is no way to check the docker logs, beyond the exit or failure reason given by ECS. Does the same docker image run OK locally?